# How do I detect when an object is at a certain coordinate using Python?

Tags: python

In Python, I want to make it so the background changes when my object moves to a certain coordinate. The only idea I had was using an *if* statement like,

```
if (turtle.position() == (100, 100):

    wn.bgpic("test1.png")
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: To the left of `turtle` you have an unnecessary unmatched bracket.

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems.

- You are using only two coordinates, you might want to add a third one *z* to make it work, because your are in 3D.
- Unless that you force it, the turtle is never going to be at exactly the point (100,100,0), it will be *enough* close. Here is a code to implement this idea (how close you want it is measured by eps).

Here is an example of hown you can make this work.

```
target=(100,100,0)
eps=0.1
if turtle.position[0]>=target[0]-eps  and turtle.position[0]<=target[0]+eps and turtle.position[1]>=target[1]-eps and turtle.position[1]<=target[1]+eps and turtle.position[2]>=target[2]-eps and turtle.position[2]<=target[2]+eps:
         print("Turtle is at target")
         bpy.ops.object.load_background_image(filepath="HERE YOU SHOULD WRITE THE FILE PATH OF YOUR IMAGE")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a driver to control material node properties for your world material:

[image]

Rigt-click on the property you want to control an click Add Driver. It will give you a terribly inconvenient floating panel that disapears every time you move your mouse away:

[image]

You can work from there calling it back by right-clicking the driven property and choosing Edit Driver, or you ca open the Drivers panel:

[image]

You will need to disable that little mouse icon for Only Show Selected and find your value in the list, then add all transform channels as variables that you can then write your expression with. It can be a boolean expression in my case since I want the Mix factor to be only 0 or only 1 so I made it that when all(x,y and z) coordinates are negative, the expression would be True that is also 1 (`x<0 and y<0 and z<0`), but you could write more conditions to define any region in space.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A variant of Martynas Žiemys' answer, perhaps easier for many:

Go to *Shading* tab, select the object of interest, Open <kbd>N</kbd>umbers panel, Switch the node editor to *World* mode:

[image]

Create a node setup like this, by dragging your $\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left mouse button* from sockets and searching for ***Mix** RGB* node, *Math: **Less** Than* node, *Vector Math: **Distance*** node. Remember to set the colors in the *Mix* node:

[image]

Now use 3 drivers, to drive the first X, Y, Z fields of the *Vector Math* node, by the X, Y, Z fields of the object's location. You do that by $\color{#888}{█0}\color{green}{█}$ *right-clicking* a source field, choosing *Copy as New Driver*, then $\color{#888}{█0}\color{green}{█}$ *right-clicking* the destination field and choosing *Paste Driver*:

[image]

This already works, though you may want to adjust the second X, Y, Z fields or the *Math: Less Than* threshold.

[image]